# Specifying method based on arity in Erlang

Tags: syntax, erlang, function-call, arity

I am having an `Erlang` module that exports two methods with the same name but different arity: `proc/1` and `proc/2`.

When using the methods in the form of `MFA` , how do you specify that the `/2` should be used or `/1`? See for example:

```
spawn(?MODULE,proc,[22])  % how to tell i want the `/1` arity  method
spawn(?MODULE,proc,[11,22]) % `/2`arity method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of elements in your list of arguments specifies if you are using `/1`or `/2`:

```erlang
1> apply(lists, reverse, [[a, b, c]]).
[c,b,a]
2> apply(lists, reverse, [[a, b, c], [tail1, tail2]]).
[c,b,a,tail1,tail2]
3> length([[a, b, c]]).
1
4> length([[a, b, c], [tail1, tail2]]).
2
```

Here I am using [`apply/3`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#apply-3) and using the `Module:Function:Args` format to first call `reverse/1` and then `reverse/2`.